# Managing CN in SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have simple MQTT Mosquitto server running on my Raspberry Pi in local network and Windows machine with simple java application in Eclipse IDE. Everything works fine if I run test application `mosquitto_sub` from my Windows machine:

```
mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.8 -t sensor --cafile c:\projects\certs\ca.crt --cert c:\projects\certs\client.crt --key c:\projects\certs\client.key -p 8884 -d -u b -P b
```

I got exception below in case I run my Java programm:

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative names present
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:324)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:641)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1368)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
```

Java programm code:

```
package artifact_id;


import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMDecryptorProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMEncryptedKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcaPEMKeyConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.jcajce.JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;

public class TestMQTT2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String serverUrl = "ssl://192.168.1.8:8884";

        String path= "C:\\projects\\certs\\";
        String caFilePath =path+"ca.crt";
        String clientCrtFilePath = path+ "client.crt";
        String clientKeyFilePath = path+ "client.key";
        String mqttUserName = "b";
        String mqttPassword = "b";

        MqttClient client;
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(serverUrl, "2");
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setUserName(mqttUserName);
            options.setPassword(mqttPassword.toCharArray());

            options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
            options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);


            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory(caFilePath,clientCrtFilePath, clientKeyFilePath, "");
            options.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);

            System.out.println("starting connect the server...");
            client.connect(options);
            System.out.println("connected!");
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            client.subscribe(
                    "/u/56ca327d17531d08e76bddd4a215e37f5fd6082f7442151c4d3f1d100a0ffd4e",
                    0);
            client.disconnect();
            System.out.println("disconnected!");


        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(final String caCrtFile,
            final String crtFile, final String keyFile, final String password)
            throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // load CA certificate
        X509Certificate caCert = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(caCrtFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            // System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }

        // load client certificate
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(crtFile));
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            // System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }

        // load client private key
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(keyFile));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();
        PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder()
                .build(password.toCharArray());
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter()
                .setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair key;
        if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted key - we will use provided password");
            key = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object)
                    .decryptKeyPair(decProv));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unencrypted key - no password needed");
            key = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
        }
        pemParser.close();

        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        caKs.load(null, null);
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(caKs);

        // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate
        // us
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert);
        ks.setKeyEntry("private-key", key.getPrivate(), password.toCharArray(),
                new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { cert });
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }


}
```

I was using same certificates as with `mosquitto_sub.exe`.

Certificates was generated in server machine according to routine below:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.crt -subj "/C=LT/ST=Some-State/O=KPV/CN=192.168.1.8"
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key -subj "/C=LT/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=192.168.1.8"
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 720
openssl genrsa -out client.key 2048
openssl req -new -out client.csr -key client.key -subj "/C=LT/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd/CN=192.168.1.103"
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out client.crt -days 720
```

Looks like I have problem with CN name in certificate, but how to fix that and why I dont have souch problem in test application `mosquitto_sub.exe` ?

UPD 
More debug before exception:

```
javax.net.ssl|INFO|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.059 EET|AlpnExtension.java:161|No available application protocols
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.060 EET|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.060 EET|SessionTicketExtension.java:396|Stateless resumption not supported
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.060 EET|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: session_ticket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.061 EET|SSLExtensions.java:257|Ignore, context unavailable extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.064 EET|ClientHello.java:652|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "1C 28 DD BE 41 96 3B 8F A6 22 7E CB 82 E2 0B 0E EF 76 40 6C D5 15 13 BF E0 7C AB 41 70 05 2B F1",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA9), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCA8), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256(0xCCAA), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=192.168.1.8
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.070 EET|ServerHello.java:887|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "6E 73 51 92 10 7B F4 71 50 89 30 98 CB DC 33 27 EA 68 5D 31 94 21 CA D2 3C 1F 01 73 B9 3B 27 6C",
  "session id"          : "75 88 F5 E8 C1 D6 04 15 B6 9C BC 00 F8 01 97 5E B2 26 D9 72 CD EB D0 20 2F 11 33 10 F4 F9 70 56",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.070 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.070 EET|ServerHello.java:983|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.071 EET|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.071 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.071 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.071 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:170|Ignore unavailable extension: session_ticket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:189|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.072 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.073 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.073 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.073 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.073 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.073 EET|SSLExtensions.java:204|Ignore unavailable extension: session_ticket
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.073 EET|SSLExtensions.java:212|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|0D|MQTT Con: 2|2020-01-07 17:44:03.079 EET|CertificateMessage.java:357|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v1",
    "serial number"      : "00 9B F1 5B 97 E0 29 8B C5",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=192.168.1.8, O=KPV, ST=Some-State, C=LT",
    "not before"         : "2020-01-07 14:55:40.000 EET",
    "not  after"         : "2021-12-27 14:55:40.000 EET",
    "subject"            : "CN=192.168.1.8, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, ST=Some-State, C=LT",
    "subject public key" : "RSA"},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "00 97 DB 51 A5 2E 74 11 D5",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=192.168.1.8, O=KPV, ST=Some-State, C=LT",
    "not before"         : "2020-01-07 14:55:08.000 EET",
    "not  after"         : "2030-01-04 14:55:08.000 EET",
    "subject"            : "CN=192.168.1.8, O=KPV, ST=Some-State, C=LT",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: EE 78 20 C5 B4 0F 52 AE   10 78 6D 4F E6 F9 01 FC  .x ...R..xmO....
        0010: C5 FE 43 3A                                        ..C:
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: EE 78 20 C5 B4 0F 52 AE   10 78 6D 4F E6 F9 01 FC  .x ...R..xmO....
        0010: C5 FE 43 3A                                        ..C:
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
```

UPD

I added SAN to my CA certificate, but still have same error:

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V1
  Subject: CN=192.168.1.8, O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=LT
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 26919970067664277046938740179646593770595070258539214027906489317270223306613773873574865971989417280121938347002713257983436007635951198166738943346774588648713868326559124372172220920255122744458481363586362998906174514508772548930887656233482327964167952459414376684269324538787753885909740701792244833405807399341202234562923325267930504133404200586110018959746363653784682525123525070031800151860156030452288371417726351186685188182156815653674462798515566058503087254867011627827960607372111926413977520280936130030617572396272525859532888254937560715723226670006379354402328441621835955075995305208788762081261
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Jan 11 23:48:05 EET 2020,
               To: Fri Dec 31 23:48:05 EET 2021]
  Issuer: CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=LT
  SerialNumber: [    ecd92b00 b3fb8404]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 10 F0 2D F7 A9 DE A8 8A   57 71 48 8E 32 CF E4 EC  ..-.....WqH.2...
0010: 6A 3B CD CB C9 85 31 72   15 75 DA 31 C6 43 28 F1  j;....1r.u.1.C(.
0020: 83 8B E2 4A A9 3E 61 CB   FE FD FB 29 17 2F 52 C4  ...J.>a....)./R.
0030: 78 0F 98 C4 B4 07 52 EA   5D DF 3C 0F E7 6B 40 D6  x.....R.].<..k@.
0040: 0D 49 30 09 86 95 12 45   4B 80 2F F0 88 E1 51 51  .I0....EK./...QQ
0050: C3 00 9B 3F AE 9D BD 60   C3 53 62 61 EC 27 6C 0A  ...?...`.Sba.'l.
0060: 9D 05 E1 C1 FE 47 1C C5   C2 73 E9 83 EB AC 40 35  .....G...s....@5
0070: AA DF 91 08 D1 1F 7C 88   D4 AA E4 0B 5E 76 96 C4  ............^v..
0080: 3F A4 D1 EC 0A FA 92 62   6D 4D 60 6E 09 C1 15 7A  ?......bmM`n...z
0090: EF 69 F8 D2 97 34 6B 85   17 DB EB E0 85 5B 65 A6  .i...4k......[e.
00A0: F9 DE 36 E3 2B 3E 6F 66   E4 8E CE C3 1B 03 35 A1  ..6.+>of......5.
00B0: 5F 69 23 7B E7 14 3C F4   55 76 A0 2A BE 2D D1 E5  _i#...<.Uv.*.-..
00C0: FB DD BB F8 35 53 74 36   03 1B BA 50 1D CE 05 9A  ....5St6...P....
00D0: CC 97 53 7A DD D8 6E 37   E7 F8 09 8A A2 6F 0D 33  ..Sz..n7.....o.3
00E0: 54 48 F3 8F EF E8 88 2C   08 AF A7 9B 36 4B A5 A1  TH.....,....6K..
00F0: B3 B3 59 BD 7D 4F 7F 2A   A8 9A F5 0C 47 7D 24 7A  ..Y..O.*....G.$z

]
chain [1] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=LT
  Signature Algorithm: SHA256withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.11

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 31551203319810981527233108446277563899213631125603579886371381656574566442248231160813967318138442441980845850377045783621105463065795094893428617296088707718259604057777847574260781634181942686117058391728751388056270282953662924658304160145891369274665499267192236359779564085533171204924942738308750731046065622639002103867771100617956654808689710961525820799371720055164697637203950227358935150462633808444574452627369987264554040538022692854734546152796362958992623680453477746700586578324657604996075661091524016670709534134322927064318932802387986606076073044828169821618812887782445389598990772050583953284467
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Jan 11 23:47:58 EET 2020,
               To: Tue Jan 08 23:47:58 EET 2030]
  Issuer: CN=192.168.1.8, O=KKK, L=London, ST=Some-State, C=LT
  SerialNumber: [    8bc631cb f446d8a2]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: 192.168.1.8
  DNSName: glass
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA256withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 71 8F 65 90 D5 B3 74 DA   56 2F 11 B0 26 83 B1 D6  q.e...t.V/..&...
0010: 2A B7 3B B3 EC 00 C4 B5   97 94 72 7F 8F 8B 59 96  *.;.......r...Y.
0020: B0 B2 8D 09 6C 04 9D CE   A7 F6 C8 9B 4D FA 10 77  ....l.......M..w
0030: 73 57 61 C2 D3 02 00 98   AC AC 17 2E B2 94 24 BD  sWa...........$.
0040: 3E D0 F3 8F 65 36 DE 47   19 27 30 13 6D 8C 98 16  >...e6.G.'0.m...
0050: D5 31 B0 41 11 35 76 E4   B9 C8 5B F9 20 5C 2C BC  .1.A.5v...[. \,.
0060: 75 6C 2F 9D D2 5B BE 11   61 59 48 D6 75 37 60 A7  ul/..[..aYH.u7`.
0070: 24 79 DF C4 A5 BE 92 6F   C0 8F 2E F1 AC 41 71 07  $y.....o.....Aq.
0080: 95 6B C6 FA E1 B3 75 76   1D 35 1E 5E 8E 14 E4 D8  .k....uv.5.^....
0090: 33 46 9F B9 98 99 70 C2   8A E6 AF 6C E8 E7 71 71  3F....p....l..qq
00A0: 76 A5 9C 0E 47 F5 24 EC   45 3C 49 EC 3F 5F 81 BA  v...G.$.E<I.?_..
00B0: CD C6 C1 31 C2 CC 4D E5   CA 88 C8 34 85 91 51 A3  ...1..M....4..Q.
00C0: 6C CB 7E 69 12 1E B8 A7   EE 3B 67 D8 7D 4D 4E 6E  l..i.....;g..MNn
00D0: 05 BC F1 E6 BA 05 DF A9   99 6B 27 D8 62 CD C8 F6  .........k'.b...
00E0: BF 7D 0D 39 BD 54 86 ED   CE 99 D7 89 45 6F 65 4A  ...9.T......EoeJ
00F0: A3 C9 9A 69 EE 46 14 6E   EF 61 64 20 82 01 E8 A5  ...i.F.n.ad ....

]
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
MQTT Con: 2, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
MQTT Con: 2, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
MQTT Con: 2, called closeSocket()
MQTT Con: 2, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
MQTT Con: 2, called close()
MQTT Con: 2, called closeInternal(true)
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1640)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:145)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:427)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1622)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: The error message states that *"No subject alternative names present"*. I would therefore expect that exactly this is the problem, i.e. that the subject is expected as SAN and not as (long obsolete) CN. This means you need to fix your certificates to include SAN.

Comment: Should I include SAN in my certificate? Is that required by server or by client library? Why test application `mosquitto_sub` works without problem?

Comment: Validation of the server certificate is done by the client. It is a tricky topic what exactly counts as subject for validation but CN is generally (i.e. not specific to MQTT) considered obsolete in favor of the more flexible SAN. Still, some implementations accept CN and SAN while other require SAN and don't check CN. So you'd better use SAN in your certificate.

Comment: you have the CN set as 192.168.1.8. Try and use a hostname and add the host name with the IP in the hosts file of your OS

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich , but how to add SAN with `openssl` ?

Comment: @vico: There are lots of information out there on how to do this. Just search for [how to add SAN with openssl](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+add+SAN+with+openssl&oq=how+to+add+SAN+with+openssl).

Comment: I added SAN to my CA certificate, but still have same error. More details in UPD

Comment: SAN belongs on the _server_ cert, NOT the _CA_ cert. Since you're using `x509 -req` for the EE certs, see https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/190905/subject-alternative-name-in-certificate-signing-request https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74345/provide-subjectaltname-to-openssl-directly-on-command-line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43690647/requested-extensions-in-csr-not-being-reflected-in-crt and https://serverfault.com/questions/845806/how-to-generate-ssl-certificate-having-ca-keys  (and links in some)